# how to solve state update on unmounted component (hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am building a quiz app and I am updating the state with an answers array each time the question is changed or a different answer is selected (in a useEffect hook). However, the app crashes after the second rerender of the second question from the Questions component. I know I didn't include all the dependency arrays (when I do the app crashes after the first render), I've also tried implementing a cleanup function but it didn't work and I am not even sure if I have to have one in this case. here is a sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-breeze-4zq4l?file=/src/Questions.js

It would be of great help if someone shares his experience of an issue like this one.

Answer (score 0):

The link seems to be out of date.